How to extract tables from pdf pages
How to extract it from pdf pages? Is there a way? I couldn't find it.
I tried to extract the tables from the pdf using camelot and tabula, but I could not do it. What I want is to extract the tables from an average of 200 to 300 pages of PDF, if there are any tables on the pages, and add them to the array.

tables = camelot.read_pdf(file_path, pages="all", line_scale=40)
